# Is it possible to pass data between 2 functional component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have two component in the same directory level. `Home` and `Checkout`. Without using Class, is it possible to pass the data between these 2 pages?

```
function Homepage() {
  const [question, setquestion] = useState("");
  ....
  ....
 return (
    <input value={question} onChange={(e) => setquestion(e.target.value)} type="text"/>
 )
}
```

Now, in the Checkout component, I need to access that value in question.

```
function Checkoutpage({ socket, props }) {
   const [question, setquestion] = ??? [How do I access question from previous page];
}
```

Comment: you should hold your `useState` in  a common parent and pass it down to both Homepage and Checkoutpage

Comment: you can use useContext when createContext is called in their mutual parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should hold your useState in a common parent and pass it down to both Homepage and Checkoutpage

```js
function Homepage({question,setquestion}) {
    return (
        <input value={question} onChange={(e) => setquestion(e.target.value)} type="text"/>
    )
}
function Checkoutpage({ socket, props,question,setquestion }) {
    question, setquestion // accesisable here
    return ...
}
function CommonParent(props) {
    const [question, setquestion] =  useState("");
    
    return <div>
        <Homepage {...{question, setquestion}}/>
        <Checkoutpage {...{question, setquestion}}/>
    </div>

}
```